# Border left interferes with top-right-radius in html2canvas while shows correctly in html

Tags: css, html2canvas

I'm making a "D" like picture with css and border radius to render it with html2canvas.

The letter is created with code:

```
  .a2 {
      width: 1em;
      height: 1em;
      border-top-right-radius: 1em;
      border-bottom-right-radius: 1em;
      border: 4px solid black;
      border-left: 0px;
    }
```

The problem is that while css shows up correctly, the canvas isn't - the top right border in canvas gets thinner at end.

[image]

Here is jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/x2LxvL0g/1/

What's wrong?

**UPDATE:**

It seems that `border-left` is interfering with `border-top-right-radius`.
I made the animation that shows top-right radius depending on `border-left` 
https://jsfiddle.net/x2LxvL0g/10/

below is screen of end of the animation:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the [documentation for html2canvas](http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/documentation/) you can see that the documentation states that the the script does not take a screenshot of the page and in fact generates a canvas based on the information.

> The script allows you to take "screenshots" of webpages or parts of
>   it, directly on the users browser. The screenshot is based on the DOM
>   and as such may not be 100% accurate to the real representation as it
>   does not make an actual screenshot, but builds the screenshot based on
>   the information available on the page.

Can i ask for the reason why you need to define the D in css but then want to display it on a canvas? Also you have used a dynamic size for your width and height but then a static size for the border width, is this intentional?

Comment: Thanks for reply. The dynamic size isn't intentional. I changed it here jsfiddle.net/x2LxvL0g/10. As for first question - i create logo that can be downloaded as png.